# Captive Runtime is always included on Flex 4.6 + Air SDK 3.8

Tags: actionscript-3, air, apk, osx-snow-leopard, flex-mobile

Adobe recently announces its new release for **[Air SDK 3.8](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1285698)**. So we have used this for our mobile application to be able to use `ServerSocket` [API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html) which is used by our created library. Upon exporting the release build, the `apk` size becomes `13.3MB` which is quite bigger compared to `3.2MB` (using the default `Flex SDK 4.6` with `Air 3.1`).

When I overlay AIR SDK 3.8 on Flash Builder 4.6, I do the following:

1. Exit **Flash Builder 4.6**
2. Download **AIR SDK 3.8** from http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/mac/download/3.8/AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2
3. Backup Flash Builder 4.6 by copying the entire directory.
4. Extract AIR SDK by using *The Unarchiver*.
5. Go to **/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6/sdks/** and copy 4.6.0
      folder then rename it to 4.6.0 + 3.8
6. Run the command:
   `sudo ditto AdobeAirSDK/ /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6/sdks/4.6.0\ + \3.8/`
7. Update application descriptor to: 
   `<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.8">`

Have I misconfigured something? Reverting back to `3.1` exports `3.2MB`.

If I will be using `Air SDK 3.1` and will run my app on an Android device with `Air 3.8` runtime, will `ServerSocket` still work?

When I export a release build for `iOS`, there's no difference on its `ipa` size. When using `3.1`, ipa size is `11.9MB`; using `3.8` still yields `11.9MB`. So what happens to `Android` releases on `AIR SDK 3.8`?

It's kinda strage that the `apk` size is greater than the `ipa` size. When exporting for `iOS` release, `8MB - 10MB` is added to the app size since the application exported has a captive runtime (*iOS does not support shared AIR Runtime*). So what happens to `Android` releases on `AIR 3.8`?

---

On exporting a release build for [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android), **captive runtime** is always included no matter what you choose on *Export Options* (Export application with captive runtime or Export application that uses a shared AIR runtime). Well, the good thing about captive runtime is that you don't have to require your user to install Adobe Air.

Comment: I was struggling with "overlaying" too, but now just use the Apache Flex 4.10.0 installer: http://flex.apache.org/installer.html

Comment: Yesterday I was packaging a very simple Android app that I developed with AIR 3.8, and I also found that **turning _captive runtime_ on/off doesn't seem to affect the size of the resulting APK file**. In either case it's ~9 MB.
My app is little more than a bare _hello world_, with no graphic assets. So packaging _without_ the runtime should yield a tiny APK… Therefore I suspect the runtime is always being included, no matter what I choose when exporting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe changed the packaging for Android in AIR 3.7. Android packages are now standard captive-runtime and the packager will warn you with something like this:

> Note: the AIR SDK no longer supports packaging android applications for use with the shared Runtime.
>   The application has been packaged with a captive Runtime`

From the documentation (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac-4f1413de12cd45ccc23-8000.html):

> Note: (AIR 3.7 and higher) By default, ADT packages a captive copy of the AIR runtime with your Android app. To force ADT to create an APK that uses an external runtime, set the AIR_ANDROID_SHARED_RUNTIME environment variable to true.

I have not tried to set that variable myself so I don't know if that actually enables you to package normally.

Answer (score 0):

3.1 doesn't support "Captive Runtime", which was added in 3.3, I believe. Captive Runtime allows you to run the application on any Android device, even if they do not have Adobe AIR installed on device. That comes with the downside of larger APK sizes, but it means your app is much more usable in the long run. Depending on AIR version, it adds between 8 and 10MB to the APK size since you are including the AIR runtime with your application

You can turn Captive Runtime on/off when you "Export Release Build" in Flash Builder, or similar in Flash Develop or Flash Pro. See the export options below:
[image]

And no, you cannot use any socket technology in AIR mobile prior to 3.8 which finally added the ability. If you build with 3.1, none of your socket code will work. I'm unsure how they handled not supporting it, but it may not even compile if you included socket code in the project (the classes may be missing for mobile projects prior to 3.8)

Comment: hi. thank you for your answer. actually, everytime I export a release build for my app, I always turn Captive Runtime off.

Comment: except for iOS since shared AIR runtime is not supported.